# Jquery autocomplete - How get count results?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

```
$(".TerminalAutocomlete").autocomplete({
        source: "./TerminalAutocomlete.php?Cmd=AdminTerminalSearchFrom",

     // full link http://testwork.ru/FL/1928673/TerminalAutocomlete.php?Cmd=AdminTerminalSearchFrom

    focus: function( event, ui ) {
    //$(this).val( ui.item.title );

    return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).val( ui.item.value );
        $(".type").val( ui.item.id );
        $(".t").val( ui.item.id );
    return false;
    }
    });
```

*Tell me please how get count result which we get with autocomplete?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".TerminalAutocomlete").autocomplete({
        source: "./TerminalAutocomlete.php?Cmd=AdminTerminalSearchFrom",
        response: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log(ui.content.length); //in this moment you get count results you 
        },
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
        //$(this).val( ui.item.title );

        return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          $(this).val( ui.item.value );
          $(".type").val( ui.item.id );
          $(".t").val( ui.item.id );
          return false;
        }
        });
```

*Enjoy!*

Answer (score 0):

use the open function in conjecture with a simple length of the list:

```
$( ".TerminalAutocomlete" ).autocomplete({
  source:"./TerminalAutocomlete.php?Cmd=AdminTerminalSearchFrom",
  open: function(event,ui){
    var len = $('.ui-autocomplete > li').length;
    console.log('Founded '+len+' results');
  }
});
```